# How do you use ligatures if word stem and syllables do not coincide?

Tags: typography, ligatures, german

I use ligatures. They are a beautiful typographic tradition and many fonts support them. Unfortunately the rules to apply ligatures are not hard and fast.

One rule says that you use ligatures only inside a morpheme [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme], which seems to be a pretty difficult subject.

Another rule (of thumb) says that you do not use ligatures across syllables.

But what do you suggest, if these two rules conflict?

I came across a single example, which is in German, a language which is more prone to misplaced ligatures, as German has many words which are composed of other words, but in those cases the rules are easily applied.

Would you use a ligature in the German word 'Hüfte' [hip]?

The stem is '**Hüft-**', that would mean: yes.

But the syllables are '**Hüf|te**', which might say: no.

I know that this is not a TeX question per se, but I know that many TeXnicians are also typography aficinoados, that's why I am hoping for some good advice here. Am I overthinking this?

Comment: I only know of the rule that you should not use ligatures that cross word joints (Wortfugen), which indeed are quite common in German. Thus, in a word such as "Kaufleute" (which consists of "Kauf" and "Leute") no ligature is used, but in "Kaufläche" (consisting of "Kau" and "Fläche") you would use a ligature (examples taken from Wikipedia). Your example "Hüfte" does not include a word joint and "Hüfte" consists of only one morphemes (I think). The Duden gives as example for the use of ligatures the word "heftig" where the ligature crosses two syllables. So, I would use a ligature in "Hüfte".

Comment: That said, this question should probably be asked over at https://german.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Your example with 'heftig' convinced me that the syllables rule is probably wrong. I'll mark this as 'answered'.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [selnolig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) package?

Comment: @StefanSchroeder: I read the passage in the Duden that is cited in Wikipedia and it seems to me that they mean that the syllable rule should be used as last resort in cases where you are unsure or where the other rules cannot be applied. But I could be wrong ...

Comment: @Mico: Sure. But I am not using it, because it's only supporting LuaLatex IIRC. Might try it though, just to have a look what it does. I am not convinced though that we should leave that decision to heuristics. Or does selnoligs use a word-list?

Comment: @StefanSchroeder - Why do you suggest that the package's rules are "based on heuristics"? The package's German language selective ligature suppression rules were based on a list of several hundred thousand words analyzed by a morpheme lexical parser. (Full disclosure: I'm the author of the package.)

Comment: And an excellent package it is (speaking from experience) :-)

Comment: @JasperHabicht - Some additional German words which contain an `ft` character pair for which the  `ft` ligature should *not* be broken up, even though the letters span a syllable boundary, are `lüften`, `vernünftlg`, `bekräftigen`, and `saftig`. In all of these cases, the syllable boundary doesn't coincide with a morpheme boundary.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the link to the selnolig package where the author also puts quite some effort in reviewing the rules for ligatures in German. I found that the Duden also says that no ligature should by typeset between the word and a suffix, except for "fi". So, this means that in "häufig" you should use a ligature, but not in "höflich". Anyways, I would not considere the "-te" in "Hüfte" to be a suffix.

Comment: @Mico: I knew you were the author of the package as I had seen your other posts, e.g. here https://texwelt.de/fragen/52/wie-kann-ich-ligaturen-verhindern My comment was not meant to denigrate your package, I am sure it does a great job (as can be seen from the positive feedback above). My point was more to determine the rule for this case, not specifically to get a solution for this single word. Also, rmligs as well as DeLig both use "only" wordlists and I just imagine that no algorithm would be able to cover all edge-cases for a read language.